# Copy data from one database to another including data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following code that can copy/clone all the tables but it doesn't copy the data in the tables. How can I tweak the code to copy the database along with data?

```
<?php

/********************* START CONFIGURATION *********************/
$DB_SRC_HOST='localhost';
$DB_SRC_USER='root';
$DB_SRC_PASS='password';
$DB_SRC_NAME='database1';

$DB_DST_HOST='localhost';
$DB_DST_USER='root';
$DB_DST_PASS='password';
$DB_DST_NAME='database2';

/*********************** GRAB OLD SCHEMA ***********************/
$db1 = mysql_connect($DB_SRC_HOST,$DB_SRC_USER,$DB_SRC_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DB_SRC_NAME, $db1) or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES;",$db1) or die(mysql_error());
$buf="set foreign_key_checks = 0;\n";
$constraints='';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $result2 = mysql_query("SHOW CREATE TABLE ".$row[0].";",$db1) or die(mysql_error());
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    if(preg_match("/[ ]*CONSTRAINT[ ]+.*\n/",$res[1],$matches))
    {
        $res[1] = preg_replace("/,\n[ ]*CONSTRAINT[ ]+.*\n/","\n",$res[1]);
        $constraints.="ALTER TABLE ".$row[0]." ADD ".trim($matches[0]).";\n";
    }
    $buf.=$res[1].";\n";
}
$buf.=$constraints;
$buf.="set foreign_key_checks = 1";

/**************** CREATE NEW DB WITH OLD SCHEMA ****************/
$db2 = mysql_connect($DB_DST_HOST,$DB_DST_USER,$DB_DST_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
$sql = 'CREATE DATABASE '.$DB_DST_NAME;
if(!mysql_query($sql, $db2)) die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DB_DST_NAME, $db2) or die(mysql_error());
$queries = explode(';',$buf);
foreach($queries as $query)
    if(!mysql_query($query, $db2)) die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: you'd have to add in a `insert into newdb.table select * from origdb.table`. you might be better off just using `mysqldump` to dump the original db's contents and then loading the dump into the new table. that'll also copy over anything else like triggers and whatnot.

Comment: @MarcB - Haha, the same SQL query I tried and failed. You should have a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849418/copying-mysql-tables-from-1-db-to-another-in-php

Comment: are the databases both on the same mysql server? I ask because you have the same host for both connections. If the user you are logging in has access to select from both databases (which root would), you can just fully qualify the database name with the table name like `dbName.tableName` and create your tables at the same time as selecting them. Something like: `CREATE TABLE db1.tableName AS SELECT * FROM db2.tableName` which will create a copy of `db2.tableName` with all the data from that database in `db1.tableName`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Yes, both on same server and lol you too should have a look at my other question where I tried the same way and it didn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26849418/copying-mysql-tables-from-1-db-to-another-in-php

Comment: If this is a continuation of a previous question, you should really just update that question instead of asking a new one. I would say to try removing the parenthesis from the `SELECT` statement in the create statement and also remove the semi-colon at the end. Also, you don't need two database connections, one will do fine. It doesn't matter what database you `mysql_select_db`, just pick one because you are specifying the database name in the query. You will still have access to the other by using the full name. Lastly, check mysql_error to see if there was a problem with your query.

Comment: No, that's not continuation of previous question. The code is entirely different and how can 1 database connection do the job? How to retrieve data from other database without establishing the connection? There is no MySQL error and when I run the SQL_Query in PhpMyAdmin it works perfectly. I just tried removing connection to second db and it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't tagged in your response and so I didn't see it. I was saying it was a continuation only because both bits of code are trying to solve the same problem, regardless if the code is different. And you only need one database connection because both connections are to the same host. If you were connecting to a different server or host, then you would need two connections to transfer the data between them. Since they are the same host, you don't need to. mysql_query only accepts one connection as a parameter and if you don't specify it, it will just use the last connection.

Comment: And about the mysql_error, I see you are using it in this code, but it is not being used in your other question which is why I suggested it.